When did "the US presidential plane" land on Diego Garcia for refueling, and which if any president was on board? (circa 2000's)

Source: BBC
I am uncertain if this is a question for History SE or Aviation SE; I've decided to try here first.
I was reading the BBC News's September 29, 2024 What I found on the secretive tropical island they don't want you to see about Diego Garcia (see also Naval Support Facility Diego Garcia)

During my time on the island, I am required to wear a red visitor pass and am closely monitored at all times. My accommodation is guarded 24-hours-a-day and the men outside make a note of when I leave and return - always under escort.
In the mid-1980s, British journalist Simon Winchester pretended his boat had run into trouble next to the island. He remained in the bay for about two days, and managed to briefly step on shore before being escorted away and told: “Go away and don’t come back.”
He tells me he remembers British authorities there being “incredibly hostile” and the island as “extraordinarily beautiful”. More than two decades later, a Time magazine journalist spent 90 minutes or so on the island when the US presidential plane stopped there to refuel.

If there were reporters on "the US presidential plane" then there's a pretty good chance there was a president on board as well. Which piqued my curiosity.
Question: When did "the US presidential plane" land on Diego Garcia for refueling, and which if any president was on board? (circa 2000's)
"bonus points" to help me understand if this was a notable occurrence, or if it turns out to be routine (except for the reporter getting off).

See also in Space Exploration SE How was an emergency landing site at Diego Garcia used during the Apollo program? (which includes a video clip of the Diego Garcia airstrip from a satellite) where there are mentions of Diego Garcia in the context of both the Apollo missions and the Space Shuttle.

I found this picture of the U.S. presidential plane at Diego Garcia, taken by Mass Communication Specialist Seaman Jonathen E. Davis:

Source: naval-technology.com
The description tells us:

Diego Garcia's executive staff including Naval Support Facility Diego Garcia's Commanding Officer Capt. Greg L. Looney and British Representative Cmdr. Gary Brooks salute Air Force One as it taxis to a stop.

Another photo by the same photographer can be found on wikimedia:

The description tells us that on september 4, 2007 :

President George W. Bush and Capt. Greg L. Looney, commanding officer of Naval Support Facility Diego Garcia, inspect military members on the flight line during the president's recent stop in Diego Garcia. President Bush stopped on the island en route to Sydney, Australia, for the Asia-Pacific Economic Co-operation forum.

Putting this together I suspect that this is the flight you are referring to.

Shortly after this answer was posted, @mins found the article in Time magazine

... We were taken to an auditorium while Bush met the base commander and troops elsewhere on the grounds.

This is consistent with the information above.
A globalsecurity.org article found by @mins explains:

This was Bush’s first visit to Diego Garcia and the first visit from any U.S. president in quite some time.

This confirms that it was a notable occurrence for a U.S. President to visit Diego Garcia.

"President George W. Bush and Air Force One during a ninety-minute
refueling stop between Iraq and Australia." - Page 7, Introduction
Note: The book describes how the island was taken from the native Chagossian people and ruined many of their lives.
Source:
https://www.amazon.com/Island-Shame-Secret-History-Military/dp/0691149836


It is likely that there were several stops or visits, it is a very important base and the period being considered is long.
